# Need to add video quality change feature in androix.media3.exoPlayer with HLS(Http Lve Streaming)

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, android-media3

I have built a media player to play some HLS urls. It is media3.exoPlayer. Now I want to add a feature where user can change the quality of the video stream. I found something here  https://proandroiddev.com/lets-dive-into-exo-player-part-ii-adding-quality-control-a0c0b50cc628 . This is exactly I wanted to do but the problem is its using android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer which is I think deprecated or soon be deprecated. I also tried to search for the solution at google but all I'm getting is old and deprecated method. Looks like the media3.exoPlayer is pretty new here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no big difference between Exoplayer from `com.google.android.exoplayer` and from `androidx.media3.exoplayer`.

At the moment, they share the same code, only under different packages.

Also, there is a quality picker implementation in the demo app, it uses media3 imports:

https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/demos/main/src/main/java/androidx/media3/demo/main/TrackSelectionDialog.java